# Настройка поддоменов на сервере

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess, домен

Нужен совет по настройкам сервера. Ищу пути решения следующих задач.

Есть сервер, допустим server.ru. Нужно программно создать (с эмулировать) домен третьего уровня (допустим sub1.server.ru) без перезапуска сервера. Потом, нужно сделать, чтобы все запросы типа:

```
sub1.server.ru/*
```

Переадресовывались на:

```
sub1.server.ru/index.php?request=*
```

Пробовал решить обе задачи с помощью файла .htaccess. Но не смог решить проблему изменения адресной строки в браузере. Т.е. при обращении к sub1.server.ru происходила переадресация к server.ru/subs/sub1, и в адресной строке отображался именно этот путь.

Если же решать проблему создания виртуальных хостов, изменяя настройки apache - необходимо перезагружать сервер, что недопустимо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, почитай [автоматические субдомены](http://server-tuning.info/apache/auto-subdomains.html).

Comment: Спасибо. Буду думать=)
п.с. как тут можно благодарность выразить? мне вот кто-то даже "учитель" поставил, а я смотел и не нашел нигде никаких галочек..

Comment: @Виталий Кустов Если ответ верен, Вы можете принять его. Если ответ, на Ваш взгляд, содержит полезную информацию, Вы можете добавить ему плюс.

Answer (score 2):

1 перезапускать не надо, достаточно apachectl reload или killall -HUP httpd

2 привести URL   sub1.server.ru/ к  sub1.server.ru/index.php?request=
можно используя систему mod_rewrite

подробнее:
[mod_rewrite](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/redirect_url.txt.html)